# Java servlet cannot send out text/plain response in JBoss

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, content-type

I have created a Java Servlet which will be deployed in JBoss. It simply responds a text "OK" or "Fail" to the client after some calculation. It works well in my development server using Tomcat 6 but it's not the case when the application server is JBoss 4.2 on production server. It appears that JBoss adds the header to the servlet response and hence my client cannot process the result. The Servlet is somewhat like this (I put everything in doGet function):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
    throw IOException, ServletException {        

    String input = request.getParameter("input");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    // response.setContentType("text/plain");

    try {
        if (functionToDoSomething(input)){
            response.getWriter().println("OK");
        }
        else {
            response.getWriter().println("FAIL.");
        }
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Normally, client would receive plain text "OK" or "FAIL" to continue the process. However, client receives something like this when the Servlet is deployed in JBoss:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY><PRE>OK
</PRE></BODY></HTML>
```

In Servlet  code I try to change the content-type but it seems doesn't work.

Are there any settings in JBoss which makes it append / override the content-type of the Servlet response? Thanks in advance for all the help.

David

Comment: I could not reproduce it (using JBoss 7). Are you sure that there is no proxy, no load balancer, no Apache with mod_proxy etc. in between which transforms the result (and fails to handle text/plain correctly)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do know there is an Apache used as a web server in between but I have no access to it. May be I should try check that out also?

Comment: Try to connect directly to the AS (bypass Apache, go to port 8080 directly). If you are not allowed to do this, you can write a JSP/servlet which uses Apache HttpClient to access your servlet directly. If that works (only text/plain), you have shown that something in between changes the result.